# Using SQL Server temp tables in ColdFusion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

ColdFusion uses `#`'s to delineate variables. In SQL Server a table name with `#` or `##` is temp table and a global temp table respectively. How does one use SQL Temp tables in ColdFusion?

Comment: You could also switch from a temp table to a CTE Common Table Expression. I find myself using these more than temp tables especially in CF code. The answer above was perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion treats shows ## as a single # in the output. Hence

```
<cfquery name="qryTempUser">
SELECT * 
FROM   ##tempUsers
WHERE  Active_CODE = 1
</cfquery>
```

is pulling from a temp table called #tempUsers

```
<cfquery name="qryTempUser">
SELECT * 
FROM   ###myTableName#
WHERE  Active_CODE = 1
</cfquery>
```

is pulling from a  temp table called that is specified in a ColdFusion variable called myTableName

```
<cfquery name="qryTempUser">
SELECT * 
FROM   ####tempUsers
WHERE  Active_CODE = 1
</cfquery>
```

is pulling from a global temp table called ##tempUsers

```
<cfquery name="qryTempUser">
SELECT * 
FROM   #####myTableName#
WHERE  Active_CODE = 1
</cfquery>
```

is pulling from a global temp table called that is specified in a ColdFusion variable called myTableName

Comment: nice followup to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666883/date-comparison-in-ms-sql-2005

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is to use stored procedures.  You have to write all that t-sql somewhere and a stored procedure might make it easier for you.