# Date issue in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a report which has the date selection as show below. When the report is first loaded it will show the data for the current month ie in this case from {ts '2014-06-01 00:00:00'} to {ts '2014-07-01 00:00:00'};range in all the queries on the page. When I select a date from the dropdown and submit the page, the queries still take the start and end date as 6/1 to 7/1 instead of the selected month. I tried debugging it but still not able to get it to work. Any suggestions here?

I have updated My form is like below. I want the first radio button to be selected on the first page load, I am just making the other selection empty on click of the radio button. Is there a way to save what is in the selection and just display results for the criteria selected?please suggest

```
   <script>
 function makeChoice() {
   var obj1 = document.getElementById('month_dt')
   var obj2 = document.getElementById('start_date')
   var obj3 = document.getElementById('end_date')

        if (document.getElementById('but1').checked) {                  
              obj2.value = '';  
              obj3.value = '';      
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('but2').checked) {
              obj1.value = '';          

        }           
    }  

   </script>
 <form name="month_year" method="get">
<div>
    <table>
    <tr>

        <th align="right">
        <input type="radio" name="datesel" value="1" id="but1" onClick="return makeChoice();"/>

        Month/Year:</th>
        <td align="left">
            <select name="month_dt" id="month_dt">
                <option value="">---Select one---</option>
                <cfloop from="0" to="#diff_month_cnt#" index="ii">
                    <cfset temp_dt = dateAdd("m", -1 * ii, today) />
                    <cfset temp_dt = createDate(year(temp_dt), month(temp_dt), 1) />
                    <cfset isselected = "" />
                    <cfif temp_dt EQ the_month_dt>
                        <cfset isselected = "selected" />
                    </cfif>
                    <option value="#dateFormat(temp_dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#" #isselected#>#dateFormat(temp_dt, "mmmm yyyy")#</option>
                </cfloop>
             </select> 

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><em>- or -</em></td></tr>
    <tr>

        <th align="right"> <input type="radio" name="datesel" value="2" id="but2" onClick="return makeChoice();"/>Start Date:</th>
        <td>
            <input id="start_date" type="text" name="start_date" <cfif isdate(url.start_Date)>value="#dateFormat(url.start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#"</cfif> size="10" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" />

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="right">End Date:</th>
        <td>
            <input id="end_date" type="text" name="end_date" <cfif isdate(url.end_Date)>value="#dateFormat(url.end_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#"</cfif> size="10" maxlength="10" autocomplete="off" />
        </td>
    </tr>

<input type="submit" value=" OK " />



 <cfif isDate(url.month_dt) and url.datesel eq 1>
    <cfset begin_dt = createDate(year(month_dt), month(month_dt), 1) /> 
    <cfset end_dt = dateAdd("m", 1, begin_dt) />    
<cfelseif isDate(url.start_date) AND isDate(url.end_date) and url.datesel eq 2 >
    <cfset begin_dt = url.start_date />
    <cfset end_dt = url.end_date />
</cfif>

<cfset the_month_dt = createDate(year(begin_dt), month(begin_dt), 1) />
```

In the queries like

```
 1)   WHERE q.quizdate >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#the_month_dt#" />
       AND q.quizdate < <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#dateAdd('m', 1, the_month_dt)#" />

 2)   WHERE r.create_dt >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#begin_dt#" />
           AND r.create_dt < <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#end_dt#" />
```

[image]

Comment: As you are using the "get" method on your form submission, what are the dates included in the URL when you submit your form?

Comment: Yes, using the get method...getting month_dt, start_date and end_date in the url...

Comment: Yes, but what are the values in the URL parameters?

Comment: Url params are coming right...if I change month/year to April 2014, month_dt is 04/01/2014, and start_date is 06/01/2014 and end_date is 07/01/2014. But when the query runs the params are start_date and end_date...and not the month April 2014.

Comment: How do you identify which selection they made? You need a way to identify if they selected month/year or start date/end date

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following code:

```
<cfif isDate(url.month_dt)>
    <cfset begin_dt = createDate(year(month_dt), month(month_dt), 1) /> 
</cfif>    
<cfif isDate(url.start_date)>
    <cfset begin_dt = url.start_date />
</cfif>    
<cfset end_dt = dateAdd("m", 1, begin_dt) />    
<cfif isDate(url.end_date)>
    <cfset end_dt = url.end_date />
</cfif>
```

to be:

```
<cfif isDate(url.month_dt)>
    <cfset begin_dt = createDate(year(month_dt), month(month_dt), 1) /> 
    <cfset end_dt = dateAdd("m", 1, begin_dt) />    
<cfelseif isDate(url.start_date) AND isDate(url.end_date)>
    <cfset begin_dt = url.start_date />
    <cfset end_dt = url.end_date />
</cfif>
```

Comment: All month_dt, start_date and end_date are all set at the same time onsubmit of the form...so that above will not work as all the conditions are true at the same time

Comment: Actually your right, your form makes no sense at all. How is the server meant to know which part of the form the user has used. You will need to add some addition data point, like radio buttons to select the search type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DaysInMonth` to look for the last date in month. As more info is given in the question, my answer is modified a bit. You need to disable and clear the values in Start/End form fields when a user chooses to select by month and vice versa. Otherwise, the users might get confused. Place the code before the form to get the start/end dates selected by a user. The final start/end dates are begin_dt and end_dt

```
<cfset thisMonth = createDate(year(now()), month(now()), 1) />

<cfparam name="url.month_dt" default="" />
<cfparam name="url.start_date" default="" />
<cfparam name="url.end_date" default="" />

<cfparam name="bRadioMonth" default="" />
<cfparam name="bRadioStartEnd" default="" />

<cfif len(url.month_dt) AND isDate(url.month_dt)>
  <cfset begin_dt = createDate(year(url.month_dt), month(url.month_dt), 1) />
  <cfset end_dt = createDate(year(begin_dt), month(begin_dt), DaysInMonth(begin_dt)) />
  <!--- Disable form fields start_date and end_date --->
  <cfset bFieldMonth = "">
  <cfset bFieldStartEnd = "disabled">
  <cfset bRadioMonth = "checked">

<cfelseif len(url.start_date) AND len(url.end_date)
      AND isDate(url.start_date) AND isDate(url.end_date)>

  <cfset begin_dt = createDate(year(url.start_date), month(url.start_date), day(url.start_date)) />
  <cfset end_dt = createDate(year(url.end_date), month(url.end_date), day(url.end_date)) />
  <!--- Disable form field month_dt --->
  <cfset bFieldMonth = "disabled">
  <cfset bFieldStartEnd = "">
  <cfset bRadioStartEnd = "checked">

<cfelse>

  <cfset begin_dt = thisMonth />
  <cfset end_dt = createDate(year(begin_dt), month(begin_dt), DaysInMonth(begin_dt)) />
  <!--- Default to disable form fields start_date and end_date --->
  <cfset bFieldMonth = "">
  <cfset bFieldStartEnd = "disabled">
  <cfset bRadioMonth = "checked">

</cfif>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
function makeChoice() {
  var fieldMonth = document.getElementById('month_dt');
  var fieldStart = document.getElementById('start_date');
  var fieldEnd = document.getElementById('end_date');

  if (document.getElementById('but1').checked) {
    fieldMonth.disabled = false;
    fieldStart.disabled = true;
    fieldEnd.disabled = true;
    fieldStart.value = '';
    fieldEnd.value = '';
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('but2').checked) {
    fieldMonth.options[0].selected = true;
    fieldMonth.disabled = true;
    fieldStart.disabled = false;
    fieldEnd.disabled = false;
  }
}
</script>
```

If form is submitted, return selected start/end dates and run query:

```
<cfoutput>
Selected Start Date: #dateFormat(begin_dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy')# End Date: #dateFormat(end_dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#
</cfoutput>

<cfif isdefined("form.submit")>
<!---
Run Query.
 1)   WHERE q.quizdate >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#begin_dt#" />
       AND q.quizdate < <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#DATEADD('d',1,end_dt)#" />

 2)   WHERE r.create_dt >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#begin_dt#" />
           AND r.create_dt < <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#DATEADD('d',1,end_dt)#" />
--->
</cfif>
```

Comment: The advantage of their original query is it will work, [regardless of whether the column contains a date -or- both a date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666883/date-comparison-in-ms-sql-2005/13687006#13687006). Using the last day of the month approach would not, and might even skip a day. But, like others mentioned, the real issue is [identifying which option was selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983251/date-issue-in-coldfusion#comment36961288_23983251).