# With stored procedures, is cfSqlType necessary?

Tags: coldfusion, sql-injection, lucee

To protect against sql injection, I read in the introduction to ColdFusion that we are to use the cfqueryparam tag.

But when using stored procedures, I am passing my variables to corresponding variable declarations in SQL Server:

```
DROP PROC Usr.[Save] 
GO 
CREATE PROC Usr.[Save] 
(@UsrID Int 
,@UsrName varchar(max) 
) AS 
UPDATE Usr  
SET UsrName = @UsrName 
WHERE UsrID=@UsrID  
exec Usr.[get] @UsrID
```

Q: Is there any value in including cfSqlType when I call a stored procedure?
Here's how I'm currently doing it in Lucee:

```
storedproc procedure='Usr.[Save]' {
    procparam value=Val(form.UsrID);
    procparam value=form.UsrName;
    procresult name='Usr';
}
```

Comment: Always data type your parameters.

Comment: Agreed. [There are several reasons for always typing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049918/coldfusion-parameterizing-a-querie/27066113#27066113). Though it refers to query parameters, the same issues apply to stored procs.

Comment: It's also a really really good idea to validate your parameters before passing them to the query. Maybe you are doing that, but I generally put `form` (as well as `url`) parameters into the `variables` scope once they've been validated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question came up indirectly on another thread. That thread was about query parameters, but the same issues apply to procedures.  To summarize, yes you should always type query and proc parameters. Paraphrasing the other answer:

> Since cfsqltype is optional, its importance is often underestimated:
>
> - **Validation:** 
>        ColdFusion uses the selected cfsqltype (date, number, etcetera) to validate the "value". This occurs *before* any sql is ever sent to
>     the database. So if the "value" is invalid, like "ABC" for type
>     cf_sql_integer, you do not waste a database call on sql that was never
>     going to work anyway. When you omit the `cfsqltype`, everything is
>     submitted as a string and you lose the extra validation.
> - **Accuracy:** 
>        [Using an incorrect type may cause CF to submit the wrong value to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049918/coldfusion-parameterizing-a-querie/27066113). Selecting the proper `cfsqltype` ensures you are
>     sending the correct value - and - sending it in a non-ambiguous format
>     the database will interpret the way you expect.
>
>   Again, technically you can omit the `cfsqltype`. However, that
>     means CF will send everything to the database as a string.
>     Consequently, the database will perform [implicit conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html)
>     (usually    undesirable). With implicit conversion, the interpretation
>     of the strings is left    entirely up to the database - and it might
>     not always come up with    the answer you would expect.
>
>   Submitting dates as strings, rather than    date objects, is a
>     prime example. How will your database interpret a    date string like
>     "05/04/2014"? As April 5th or a May 4th? Well, it depends. Change the
>     database or the database settings and the result may be    completely
>     different.
>
> The only way to ensure consistent results is to specify the
>   appropriate `cfsqltype`. It should match the data type of the target
>   column/function (or at least an equivalent type).

Comment: In rare cases, implicit conversion can also negatively impact query performance. In some cases, the optimizer may decide it must cast the values of an indexed column to different type in order to perform a comparison. That may result in a poor execution plan.  Optimizers are usually smart enough to avoid that, but .. it can happen on occasion. Using the correct type avoids the issue altogether.

Comment: Does this mean we should also type query parameters which are not going to change like integers? e.g. <cfqueryparam value = "1" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer">

Comment: @TusharBhaware - IMO, no. Using an explicit `cast/convert` is more appropriate for static values than using cfqueryparam. The primary purpose of query parameters is to help the database engine cache the execution plan of a query with whose values may change. When the values are static, databases like SQL Server will cache the plan anyway, even without cfqueryparam. So IMo, you are better of using an explicit `cast/convert` instead. Honestly, I do not always use `cast` for simple `bit` or `int` flags ie 1/0, but I do for ambiguous values like date strings, decimals, etcetera.