# SQL ID from table posts same ID to all other coldfusion entries per transaction

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

How do I trigger my ID from my Transaction table to be the same on all entries to each table per session? I am trying to insert a lot of information to many tables but trying to keep all tables linked together by TransactionID and am struggling on how it creates the TransactionID with the first entry then grabbing that entry and using it on all other table entries.

(This is my insert to create the Transaction. This should automatically create an ID in my Transaction table since ID is my primary key in the transaction table and IsIdentity is yes and increment of one)

```
<cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="InsertEntry">
 INSERT INTO dbo.Transaction (Type, OwnerType)
 VALUES (
    <cfqueryparam value='NonLeased' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='Owner' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
 )
</cfquery>
```

This then creates the transaction table:
ID: 1
Type: NonLeased 
OwnerType: Owner

I am trying to figure out how I can keep that same transaction ID to be inserted with my next entries to my other 6 Tables (if the table exists)

```
<cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="CustomerInsertEntry">
 INSERT INTO dbo.Customer (TransactionID, ID, FirstName, LastName)
 VALUES (
    <cfqueryparam value= **'(ID from Transaction Table)'** cfsqltype='cf_sql_int' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='1' cfsqltype='cf_sql_int' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.firstname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.lastname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
 )
</cfquery>
```

This is completely new to me and have done lots of research I just keep coming across sql commands of triggers and all but have no idea how that applies with my coldfusion set up like this.

Comment: "Transaction" is a reserved word in SQL Server, making it a poor choice for a table name. Consider renaming the table. Also, one of the query params is using an incorrect type. It should be `cf_sql_integer`, not `cf_sql_int`. Unfortunately, CF does not warn you about misspellings, so you could enter "cf_sql_grapefruit" and the CF server would allow it. However, then it defaults to passing the parameters as strings, [which is undesirable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29436751/104223).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `cfquery` you can use the results attribute to return information based on the query that was run. One part of this information is `GENERATEDKEY`.
You can then assign this `GENERATEDKEY` to a variable and use it later in your code.

So first you need to add the result attribute to your first `cfquery`.

```
<cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="InsertEntry" result="transactionResult">
 INSERT INTO dbo.Transaction (Type, OwnerType)
 VALUES (
    <cfqueryparam value='NonLeased' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='Owner' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
 )
</cfquery>
```

Then assign a variable to use the `GENERATEDKEY` from the result (or use the result variable directly)

i.e. `<cfset theID = transactionResult.GENERATEDKEY>`

Then you use this variable anywhere else in your code.

```
<cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="CustomerInsertEntry">
 INSERT INTO dbo.Customer (TransactionID, ID, FirstName, LastName)
 VALUES (
    <cfqueryparam value='#theID#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_integer' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='1' cfsqltype='cf_sql_integer' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.firstname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='#session.checkout.info.lastname_1#' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
 )
</cfquery>
```