# SQL Syntax Error submitting query with coldfusion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I am getting this error and cannot find where my syntax is messed up can anyone please help me with what I am overlooking!

```
    [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the
    keyword 'Transaction'. 



<cfquery datasource="Titlesbymail" name="InsertEntry" result="transactionResult">
 INSERT INTO dbo.Transaction (Type, OwnerType)
 VALUES (
    <cfqueryparam value='NonLeased' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
   , <cfqueryparam value='Owner' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
 )
</cfquery>
```

My database looks like this :
[image]

The ID should be set up to automatically increment by 1 and the date time should automatically know it based on the getdate() function. So I am very unsure how I am making an error here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you have named your table using a SQL reserved word; `Transaction`. I would not recommend that as you may run into issues (like you have now).

However, it can be done.  Try this and see if it works:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transaction] (Type, OwnerType)
VALUES (
   <cfqueryparam value='NonLeased' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
  , <cfqueryparam value='Owner' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' />
)
```

List of SQL Server reserved keywords: [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Comment: Good answer. Especially for recommending against using reserved words as table names!

Comment: @Vicki - Yep.  This is exactly why [I recommended renaming the table on your other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866864/sql-id-from-table-posts-same-id-to-all-other-coldfusion-entries-per-transaction#comment47869268_29866864) ;-)

Comment: You just now made the change after 5 months? What error message are you getting when attempting the insert?  This question had to do with your "transaction" table, not a "customer" table.  It might be best for you to enter a new question.  You can refer back to this question if it is helpful for the context of your new question.