# What are the CFSQLType on QueryExecute

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

When I look at

```
QueryExecute ("select from Artists where artistid=? and country=?",
    [1, "USA"], {datasource="cfartgallery"});
```

I am wondering if `artistid` is queried as if were

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="1">
```

From 
    https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/QueryExecute

Comment: FWIW, enabling full debugging will show the cfsqltype in CF11. Example `Query Parameter Value(s) -
Parameter #1(CF_SQL_CHAR) = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you need to provide additional attribute as a Query parameter (like
> *CFSQLType*, list, and separator), you can pass these as struct against
> that column name.
>
> **Example 2**
>
> ```
> QueryExecute("select from Employee where country=:country 
>   and citizenship=:country", 
>   {country={value='USA', CFSQLType='CF_SQL_CLOB', list=true}});
> ```

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/QueryExecute

Comment: So if CFSQLType is not specified, then it defaults to `cf_sql_varchar` ?

Comment: @JamesAMohler I believe so, just like `cfqueryparam` without specifying type.  Usually it'll work but if there's an index for that column, but the type is not specified, the DB may not utilize the index.

Comment: Henry, actually the default for cfqueryparam is `cf_sql_char`.  *the DB may not utilize the index* Most db's are usually smart enough to coerce the literal into the correct type, rather than the column values, which would hinder index usage. Though not always. However, omitting the type also means you lose validation and submit the value as a string [which can cause bigger issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434159/with-stored-procedures-is-cfsqltype-necessary/29436751#29436751)

Comment: As an aside, what the heck is with the `CF_SQL_CLOB` in the CF docs? I am having Dreamweaver flashbacks ;-)

Comment: @Leigh ya, sometimes it's scary to think what sort of CFML Adobe engineers write...