# CF queries using form variables entered by a user

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to do a query matching my trans_location column with the form data the user enters. I have a dropdown that lets the user choose multiple locations. When they choose multiple it places commas in between each location. When I choose only one location the results come back correct with the correct location. But when I choose more than one location it does not find any of the locations. Do the commas make it only one name and it will not search each location?

[image]

```
<cfset result = {} /> 
<cftry>
    <cfset date1 = #CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.StartDate & '00:00:00')#>
    <cfset date2 = #CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.EndDate & '23:59:59')#>

    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
        SELECT *
        FROM cl_checklists
        WHERE date >= #date1# AND date <= #date2#
        AND trans_location = '#form.Location#'
    </cfquery>

<cfoutput>#date1#</cfoutput>
<cfoutput>#date2#</cfoutput>

<cfdump var="#GetLocationInfo#">

    <cfcatch type="any"> 
        <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message > 
        <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail > 
    </cfcatch> 
</cftry>
```

I also tried doing something like this:
`AND trans_location =  <cfqueryparam value='#form.Location#' />`

Comment: Not related to your question, but I find select controls that allow multiple selections to really easy to mess up.  You might consider checkboxes instead.

Comment: Side note, if you need to filter on entire dates, the correct comparison is `WHERE Col >= {startDateAtMidnight} AND Col < {dayAfterEndDateAtMidnight}`]. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27062906/104223) for more details and the proper cf_sql_type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `IN` [operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) in conjunction with `cfqueryparam` with the `list="true"` attribute. (Here is a quick helpful tutorial for cfqueryparam: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/677.cfm)

Lastly: always, *always*, **always** use `cfqueryparam` when sending parameters to the database.

```
<cfset result = {} />
<cftry>
    <cfset date1 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.StartDate & '00:00:00')>
    <cfset date2 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.EndDate & '23:59:59')>

    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
        SELECT  *
        FROM    cl_checklists
        WHERE   date >=  <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND date <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.location#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
    </cfquery>

<cfoutput>#date1#</cfoutput>
<cfoutput>#date2#</cfoutput>

<cfdump var="#GetLocationInfo#">

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message >
        <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail >
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```