# How can I CFLoop a query in another query correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, cfloop

*Background/Purpose:*  I am creating a coldfusion document that contains SQL for grabbing values from my company's database.  I am finding the conversion rate (Licenses Sold / Registrations) per Sales Rep on our team.  Each Rep has an ID ( `RegionalDirectorID`)  tied to users to help keep track.

*Question/Problem:* The problem is that we have other workers that sell licenses here or there, such as our CEO, Head Developer etc.  We have 8 sales reps with the `UserType` of 8.  I am using another query to select those UserTypes, to differentiate from other people so that our data doesn't get mixed up selecting them too.

As you can see below, I am using a cfloop to loop thru the `getUsers` query, specifically to help the line`(Users.RegionalDirectorID = #getUsers.UserID#)` print out all of the ID's of our sales reps.  **When I don't have the cfloop entered, I only get one row showing one sales rep.  If I do have the cfloop, I will get the last sales rep.**

**Code:**

```
<cfset myQuery = QueryNew("ID, ConversionRate")> 

<cfquery name="getUsers" datasource="#dsn#">
    Select UserID FROM USERS WHERE 
    UserTypeID = 8
    AND ISACTIVE = 1
</cfquery> 

<cfquery name="getREGRD" datasource="#dsn#">
 Select COUNT(DISTINCT(Users.UserID))  AS TOTALREG, RegionalDirectorID
 FROM Users
 WHERE UserTypeID = 3
<!---   <cfloop query="getUsers">
    AND (Users.RegionalDirectorID = #getUsers.UserID#)
    </cfloop>--->
AND (PARENTID IS NULL OR PARENTID = 0)
        <cfif len(selectMonth)>
            AND MONTH(Users.DateStamp) = #selectMonth#
        <cfelse>
            AND MONTH(Users.DateStamp) = #MONTH(NOW())#
        </cfif>
        GROUP BY Users.RegionalDirectorID
</cfquery> 

<cfquery name="getREGRDSold" datasource="#dsn#">
    Select COUNT(DISTINCT(UserTractLicense.UserID))  AS TOTALSOLD, Users.RegionalDirectorID
    FROM  Users, UserTractLicense 
    WHERE Users.UserID = UserTractLicense.UserID 
    AND   Users.UserTypeID = 3 AND
    (PARENTID IS NULL OR PARENTID = 0)
    <cfif len(selectMonth)>
            AND MONTH(Users.DateStamp) = #selectMonth#
    <cfelse>
            AND MONTH(Users.DateStamp) = #MONTH(NOW())#
    </cfif>
    GROUP BY Users.RegionalDirectorID
</cfquery> 

<!---<cfset newRow = QueryAddRow(myQuery, #getREGRD.RecordCount#)>
    <cfloop query="getREGRD">
        <cfset QuerySetCell(myQuery, "ID",  #getREGRD.RegionalDirectorID#, getREGRD.currentRow) />
    </cfloop>   
    <cfloop query="getREGRDSold">
        <cfset QuerySetCell(myQuery, "ConversionRate", #getREGRDSold.TOTALSOLD#/#getREGRD.TOTALREG#, getREGRDSold.currentRow) /> 
    </cfloop>
--->

<!---<cfdump var="#myQuery#">--->
<cfdump var="#getREGRD#">
<cfdump var="#getREGRDSold#">

<cfoutput query="getREGRDSold">
    #getREGRDSold.RegionalDirectorID#
</cfoutput>
```

The cfloop was causing the newQuery to shoot out the error below. That is why some of it is commented out:

> An error occurred while evaluating the QueryAddRow function: Parameter> 2, 0, of the QueryAddRow function must be a positive integer. 
> The
>   error occurred on line 70.

The resulting data has some RegionalDirectorID's that do not have the UserTypeID of 8, such as the NULL cells, which I would like to remove from the results of the query.

[image: Sample Results]

Comment: Sounds excessively complicated.  Maybe you should rethink the requirement to exclude the 8's, or let the user decide whether or not to include them.

Comment: Your question is not clear, ie an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If the results should only include `UserTypeID = 8` (sales rep) why are two of queries using `UserTypeID = 3`? What is UserTypeID = 3?

Comment: I agree with Leigh. It seems like your initial queries could be written in such a way as to avoid the steps your are asking about here.

Comment: @Leigh Sorry the question is not clear, let me try to explain in comment and if you understand then I will add it to the question.                                                      Each customer has the `UserTypeID = 3`.  Each customer has a `RegionalDirectorID` attached to it, to help find out which sales rep is helping them.  I took a look at our database, and there seems to be a problem with `RegionalDirectorID`...I will figure this all out with a coworker of mine so I can correctly present the problem.

Comment: @Leigh So selecting all of the users with the `UserTypeID = 3`, we are selecting all of our customers.  Each customer has a `RegionalDirectorID` attached to help seperate sales reps' leads.  **Each Sales Rep's UserID is equal to the `RegionalDirectorID` attached to their lead(customer).**  I am looping through a query that selects the `UserID` of our sales reps in another query, and seeing if they equal one of the `RegionalDirectorID`s that show up with our customers selected in the `getREGRD` (or registrations) query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is a single JOIN, instead of all the extra looping and queries.

If the `Users` table stores *both* customers and sales reps, you will need a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it). In other words, join the `Users` table to itself by using [aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)). Then filter each one on the appropriate user types. Something like this:

```
SELECT  cust.RegionalDirectorID
        , COUNT(DISTINCT(lic.UserID))  AS TOTALSOLD
FROM    Users cust
           INNER JOIN Users sales ON sales.UserID = cust.RegionalDirectorID
           INNER JOIN UserTractLicense lic ON lic.UserID = cust.UserID
<!--- customers --->
WHERE   cust.UserTypeID = 3 
<!--- sales reps --->
AND     sales.UserTypeID = 8
... etcetera 
GROUP BY cust.RegionalDirectorID
```

A few other comments:

1. While not always technically required, it is a good practice to fully qualify *all* column names whenever a query involves multiple tables.
2. Along the same lines, be sure to scope all variables. For example, use `FORM.selectMonth` or `URL.selectMonth` instead of just `selectMonth`.
3. Always use `cfqueryparam` on all variable query parameters. The most important reason is to protect your database from sql injection. It also helps improves performance for queries executed multiple times.

> `MONTH(Users.DateStamp) = #selectMonth#`

4. I noticed the query only filters on month number (not month *and* year). So if selectedMonth = 8, the query will return results for the month of "August" - in *any* year. Was that your intention? If not, you will obviously want add a year filter as well. However, using functions on an indexed column usually prevents the database from utilizing indexes. So you might consider using [this paradigm which is more index friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666883/date-comparison-in-ms-sql-2005/13687006#13687006):

   ```
    WHERE  TheDateColumn >= TheStartDateAtMidnight         
    AND    TheDateColumn < TheDayAfterEndDateAtMidnight
   ```

Comment: I'm still looking over your answer, but I noticed your question on 4...I just have to add a ColdFusion line that states `YEAR(DateStamp) = #Year(NOW())#`

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a syntax error with the query right now, but once I figure it out it should be good to go!

Comment: Could be a typo in the psuedo example above. Just noticed one in the FROM clause, ie "user" instead of "users". My bad.

Comment: No worries, I caught that